# I'm hosting a version controlled folder to the internet; but switch to development branch could break service

Tags: git, version-control

I'm creating a service hosted on the web. The **master branch** has well tested code that is by and large safe for users.

When I want to add features, I need to switch to the **development branch**, and this involves tweaking the code - an action that might break the service.

How can I **add features and test for changes** while making the tested code available to users.

I have tried using two different folders, but this seems tedious. Are there tools that help with this?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, I'm afraid what you're really asking is how to access/write/run development code in a production environment, without affecting production users.

The only way to do this is to separate out your production environment from a dev and/or UAT environment.

On a git level, this would be done by setting up two separate local repositories, one that your production service runs off, the other that you're free to play around in.

You may want to look at Git Worktree, but not sure if that will help you achieve your aim.